# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-junit

I am trying to set up a cucumber framework for my project.
    I am getting following error.Not sure if this is related to Junit versioning upgrade.

```
 Exception in thread "main"``java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.junit.runner.Description.createSuiteDescription(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/Serializable;[Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;)Lorg/junit/runner/Description;
at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.getDescription(FeatureRunner.java:43)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.describeChild(Cucumber.java:88)
```

My PoM.xml file looks like this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0                         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>Salesforce_CloudinIT</groupId>
<artifactId>SCIT</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.5</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
enter code here
</project>
```

Comment: What does `mvn dependency:tree` shows? Do you see multiple different versions of cucumber / junit components there?

Comment: Hi Ivan,Thanks for your assistance.Just sorted that.It was due to incorrect versioning.